# How to implement an async File.Delete/Create/Move?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, io, task-parallel-library, async-await

Since I have to do a lot of file I/O operations in my application,
I decided to implement them asynchronously.
Looking into the MSDN, there are no asynchronous counterparts for File.Create, File.Delete and File.Move. As I learned, the reason is the nonexistence of an asynchronous Win32 implementation for file delete, create or move, So I ended up with the following solution:

```
public static Task DeleteAsync(string path)
{
     Guard.FileExists(path);

     return Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path));
}

public static Task<FileStream> CreateAsync(string path)
{
     Guard.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(path);

     return Task.Run(() => File.Create(path));
}

public static Task MoveAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
     Guard.FileExists(sourceFileName);
     Guard.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(destFileName);

     return Task.Run(() => { File.Move(sourceFileName, destFileName); });
}
```

Considering the paradigma ["Don’t use Task.Run in Libraries"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) , I am wondering if there is a better implementation or should I fallback to synchronous code?

Many thanks in advance!

Edits:

---

- Improved the code based on Peter Duniho recommendation
- Added the link to the original blog post provided by Sriram Sakthivel

Comment: Who says "don't use `Task.Run()` in libraries"? How do you think you could execute synchronous methods without using either that, or something equivalent to that? Is there anything actually wrong with the implementation you have?

Comment: @PeterDuniho It is stephen cleary's recommendation. He recommends not to use `Task.Run` in implementation, if you need to wrap synchronous method as asynchronous operation, then do it in client code where you need it. Edit: Also Stephen toub says that don't expose asynchronous wrapper over synchronous methods.

Comment: By the way, your implementations do seem less-than-perfect. The methods should all just return the `Task` (without configuring await, and without the methods being `async`). `CreateAsync()` can `return Task.Run(() => File.Create(path));` (i.e. the awaitable task returned would itself return the `FileStream` object...no need to await yourself to do that, nor to use variable capturing to accomplish it).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Cleary's opinion is certainly respected, but it's just one opinion. _Why_ does he recommend against this, and should it really be taken as an absolute or is it just a general suggestion? Do you have a reference? What is one to do if the _entire goal_ is to provide an asynchronous library for things which are otherwise inherently synchronous? Why should client code have to keep wrapping the same things over and over, when a library could provide the same?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I guess I found it http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html. I can't recall what he said, you can read it :)

Comment: Beside the performance penatly (which could be discussed) in his ASP.NET scenario there's no technical reason why you shouldn't use this approach. His only argument is, that it's a "code smell" and that it's not the best solution because it's a code smell (which maybe is correct).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: thanks. Given that Cleary defers to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), I guess the advice really comes from Stephen Toub. Still, while I get the general point, it doesn't seem like the worst thing to do here per se. To me, the bigger argument against making these operations `async` is that _they don't need to be_. Create, Move, and Delete are all very quick operations; the overhead of the async version likely exceeds that of the actual operation! That seems like a better reason to just "don't do that". :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho They are very fast operations when they succeed... On failure they can be quite slow :) (you know when you try to delete a file, and the file is in use, and five seconds later the Explorer tells you that the file is in use, and you hate it :-) )

Comment: @xanatos: yes, that's true. see the note in my answer where I acknowledge this, as a possible justification for the approach in specific scenarios. It does depend on how broadly these operations are going to be used by the OP.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Many thanksI updated my code according your recommendation.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I was exactly referring to the Cleary's blog post.Many thanks for providing the link.

Comment: @xanatos: Indeed. That's the main reason why I want them to be asynchronous. Ok an asynchronous implementation of File.Create is doubtful, but delete and move can be long running, even if the operation is successful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Toub's thought-provoking article.  I think it is a mistake to sum up the entire article as "never wrap a synchronous op in an asynchronous op".  He seems to be referring partly to not doing this in a library to allow the library user to make the decision.  He also says not to do this if the library user will end up immediately waiting on the task to finish.  Finally, his last 2 paragraphs provide examples around file I/O operations which introduce external delays.  The OP is asking if this is a good DRY solution for his application, not a library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you must do this, I would write the methods like this (note: I readily agree that this is exactly what Stephens Cleary and Toub are urging us not to do):

```
public static Task DeleteAsync(string path)
{
     Guard.FileExists(path);

     return Task.Run(() => { File.Delete(path); });
}

public static Task<FileStream> CreateAsync(string path)
{
     Guard.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(path);

     return Task.Run(() => File.Create(path));
}

public static Task MoveAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
     Guard.FileExists(sourceFileName);
     Guard.IsNotNullOrWhitespace(destFileName);

     return Task.Run(() => { File.Move(sourceFileName, destFileName); });
}
```

This cleans up the code a bit and eliminates excessive context/thread-switching.

In the context of a GUI-based program, it seems fine to use wrappers like these. I think as long as you don't create a whole new library with synchronous and asynchronous APIs in parallel, as described in the articles referred to, this isn't terrible.

But for me, the bigger problem is that none of these operations are likely to take long enough to justify making them asynchronous in the first place. I.e. the usual reason you run things in a `Task` from a UI thread is because your UI thread can't afford to wait around while the operation completes. But here, for each of these operations, the act of sending the operation to the thread pool, and then picking up with the continuation after it's done, are likely to add as much performance overhead to your program as the operation itself.

It's for *that* reason that I would recommend against bothering with an asynchronous version of the methods at all. Just call the `Create()`, `Delete()`, and `Move()` methods from the UI directly.

(Note: one exception to the above is if dealing with a network share or different volumes, where a `Move()` involves actually copying data. So even there, it's a big huge "it depends". Similarly, while `Delete()` and `Create()` would normally be fast even over a network, they could take awhile if the operation actually is going to fail. You may actually have a good use case for running the operations asynchronously there).

Comment: As a sidenote, using `Guard.FileExists(sourceFileName)` synchronously is probably wrong. If the `sourceFileName` is on another computer, that is slow to reply, then you have returned to point 0 :-)

Comment: @xanatos: yes, I agree with that observation as well. Without seeing the implementation it's not possible to know for sure, but it seems safe to assume it's just delegating to `File.Exists()` and throwing an exception if it returns `false`.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: In WinRT all the file operations are asynchronous, so I was wondering if this isn't also beneficial for common .NET applications. Ok an asynchronous implementation of File.Create is doubtful, but delete and move can be long running, even if the operation is successful. Would it be a good approach in your opinion to just implement Move async and Create/Delete being synchronous?

Comment: @Peter Duniho: Yes File.Exits is exactly implemented like you described. I forgot to leave it out of my example code.

Comment: @Fabe: WinRT is a slightly different beast, in that its API has specifically abstracted the cloud, and with the expectation that using the cloud is the standard scenario. That's a good thing, but it makes it all too likely that file operations normally thought of as very fast could be slow. In any case, even on the desktop, _depending on the scenario_, you could have latency on all three of these operations, so you _may_ be justified in using async wrappers after all.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. Since I am dealing with files < 1MB on a local drive, I will follow your recommendation and just perform them synchronously.

Comment: @Fabe: note that if you mean the files are always on the same drive, then the size is irrelevant, even for `Move()`. Obviously `Create()` and `Delete()` wouldn't depend on the file size (well, I suppose a custom file system driver that implements secure delete might), but even `Move()` simply updates directory information; no data is literally moved on the disk as long as the source and destination on the same drive.

Comment: If you wrap IO-bound work in Task.Run() then you’re just pulling a new thread out to run the code synchronously, It may have a similar signature because it’s returning a Task, but all you’re doing is blocking a different thread.